# Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot find data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssms

I have created a table type like below:

```
CREATE TYPE EFF AS TABLE
(
      F numeric(15)
)
```

But when I'm declaring this table variable`DECLARE @EFF  EFF ;`
I'm getting this error

> Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot find data type.

Comment: I know it is not SQLServer 2008 but it works fine like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=456d239ebbad167d54bcd5ca14434ee4 Maybe you can give us more details on where the error is produced...

Answer (score 0):

add `GO` before `type` declaration. Object creation must be committed first before declaring any variables.

```
CREATE TYPE EFF AS TABLE
(
     F numeric(15)
);

GO

DECLARE @eff EFF;

INSERT INTO @eff VALUES (10)

SELECT * FROM @eff;

DROP TYPE EFF
```